# Sort grease pencil layers?

Tags: grease-pencil, properties, collections, layers

I would like to know if its possible to sort the [grease pencil's `layers` property collection](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.GreasePencil.html#bpy.types.GreasePencil.layers), like we can sort any other collection.

Like, maybe kind of accessing its list to call sort (with an specific key/function), or simply by being able to call `move(index, new_index_position)`.

I noticed that the `move()` function in `gpencil.layers` takes a layer and a string for the movement direction ("UP" or "DOWN").

I'm making some kind of "bulk sorting" of all layers, and sorting them by some differents criteria and I'm not sure if using the move() is the best approach, since that `move()` seems to be calling the operator that moves a single layer up and down, and I think is not the best way to sort the layers via script. So I would like to know if I'm missing a best way to do it.

Thank you so much for the help, much appreciated.